# self.Rotate() is not a function in prototype

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at the other questions that are similar to mine, but I can't seem to find an answer.

The error that I'm having is in the title as well:

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.Rotate() is not a function
```

Here's the full code where this happens:

```
var Card = function(renderer, stage) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = "None";
    self.health = 5;

    self.renderer = renderer;
    self.stage = stage;

    self.sprite = null;

    PIXI.loader.add("FirePlace/GW2-Logo.jpg").load(self.Setup);
};

Card.prototype.Setup = function() {
    self.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["FirePlace/GW2-Logo.jpg"].texture);
    console.log(self.stage);
    self.stage.addChild(self.sprite);
    console.log("Sprite loaded");
    self.renderer.render(self.stage);
    self.Rotate();
};

Card.prototype.SetName = function(name) {
    self.name = name;
};

Card.prototype.Rotate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(self.Rotate);

    if (self.sprite === null)
        console.log("Sprite is null");

    if (self.sprite !== null && self.sprite.rotation <= 1.5708)
        self.sprite.rotation += 0.03;

    self.renderer.render(self.stage);
};
```

At the end of the Setup function I try to call the Rotate function and this is where it fails.

Comment: `self` is not defined among the functions of your class, at the beginning of your functions, you need to add `var self = this;`

Comment: Define it before you use it.

Comment: Also unless you have another function closure, you don't even need self, just use this.

Comment: The only reason to assign `self` is if you're calling methods that rebind `this`.

Comment: @Dries Can you give us a fiddle? Please?

Comment: @ahitt6345 here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/xo9ey0fr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this code prevents the addChild problem that you had. Look at the comments in the code for explanation.

```
var Card = function(renderer, stage) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = "None";
    self.health = 5;

    self.renderer = renderer;
    self.stage = stage;

    self.sprite = null;
    var x = function(){
        self.Setup.apply(self,arguments); 
    }
    PIXI.loader.add("FirePlace/GW2-Logo.jpg").load(x); // origionally: PIXI.loader.add("FirePlace/GW2-Logo.jpg").load(self.Setup);
    // self would not be defined in whatever other context it is used in when it is called. All I had to do was wrap it in a function and it was fixed
};

Card.prototype.Setup = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["FirePlace/GW2-Logo.jpg"].texture);
    console.log("Stage is:",self.stage); // Now stage is defined since I wrapped this function in another function.
    self.stage.addChild(self.sprite);
    console.log("Sprite loaded");
    self.renderer.render(self.stage);
    self.Rotate();
};

Card.prototype.SetName = function(name) {
    var self = this; // I also defined self = this in every single function :D
    self.name = name;
};

Card.prototype.Rotate = function() {
    var self = this;
    var x = function(){
        if (self.sprite === null)
        console.log("Sprite is null");

        if (self.sprite !== null && self.sprite.rotation <= 1.5708) 
            self.sprite.rotation += 0.03;

        self.renderer.render(self.stage);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(x);
    }; // Same goes for this one. 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(x);


};
```

Comment: Amazing @ahitt6345, this works as expected. Is there an explanation why things need to be so difficult? I am a c#/c++ programmer normally and this `var self = this` stuff in every function and then the function inside the prototype functions really don't make sense to me.

Comment: What you just asked is another whole stackoverflow question of its own. Let me find it for you.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/4309643 It basically explains the `this` keyword and all of it's glorious weirdness.

Comment: I asked it since I didn't find anything about it. Huge thanks for the link and the help!

Comment: No problem :D I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Within `Card.prototype.Setup`, and your other methods later added to your `Card.prototype`, `self` is `window.self`, because `var` is private and not part of the properties which your Constructor inherits from its prototype Object. Change `self` to `this` or `Card` (if you prefer the context to be bound) in there for the context you seek.

Comment: Not exactly a reserved word... you may use it as any identifier, arbitrarily. It's just [a common idiom to use `self` to get the current object](http://justjs.com/posts/this-considered-harmful) because `this` will not be captured from the context (and, also, because there is `window.self`).

Comment: Since `window` is implicit `self` is `window.self` if not assigned to a `var`.

Comment: when I try to change the `self.Rotate()` to `Card.Rotate()` or `this.Rotate()` I get the same error

Comment: @Dries Did you try to replace all instances of `self` with `this`?

Comment: @ahitt6345 if I do that I get another error (addChild not found). That's why initially changed everything to the `self` thing

Comment: You'll figure out the word `this` eventually.